# Last Successful Artifacts List

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I would like to create an archive of the *.jar files in hudson. Currently it does not list the *.jar files created by the build. Is there an addon for this, or is there setup required, if so where?

Here is what I would like it to look like. 
[image: current]
<sub>(source: [nabble.com](http://hudson.361315.n4.nabble.com/file/n598065/hudson1.jpg))</sub>

Here is what i currently have.
[image]
<sub>(source: [nabble.com](http://hudson.361315.n4.nabble.com/file/n598065/hudson2.jpg))</sub>

edit: also do i need to play with include sets in order to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the project properties.  Click on the option "Archive the artifacts", and enter a pattern matching the artifacts you want to keep.  For example, `*.jar`.

Comment: now its saying that the directory i am pointing it to doesn't exist. even thought i am there in the console.

Comment: You can always use \*\*/\*.jar to say "scan the whole file tree and find all files that match '*.jar'".

Comment: Can you use an absolute filepath?

Answer (score 6):

The presentation is changed based on the number of files you're archiving. There are three modes:

- Plain list
- Tree
- Simple link

To control how many files need to be present before it switches to another presentation mode, set the system properties:

- `hudson.model.Run.ArtifactList.listCutoff` (default 16)
- `hudson.model.Run.ArtifactList.treeCutoff` (default 40)

Example `java` call:

> `java -Dhudson.model.Run.ArtifactList.listCutoff=40 -Dhudson.model.Run.ArtifactList.treeCutoff=100 -jar jenkins.war`