# Why do Jenkins artifacts sometimes not show as links?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use scripted pipeline to create this build and at the end I do this

```
stage('archive'){
    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'logs/**'
}
```

To archive the logs to get this clickable link table in the project screen..

[image]

However this somehow does not work with other project with the same pipeline. The logs structure is the same but it shows this blank as in the image below. If you click on Last Successful Artifacts the logs are there but the links are not. Does anyone know why the links dont show up? How do you debug this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presentation of the artifacts depends on the number of files that are archived as artifact by a build. Depending on the number of files Jenkins is showing artifacts either as *plain list* (16 or less files), *foldout tree* (40 or less files) or as *simple link* (more than 40 files).

Since your scripted pipeline is using a wild card for archiving artifacts, it depends on the specific project how many files are archived. In your first example 7 files are archived and presented as *plain list*. In your second example apparently more the 40 files are archived and the *simple link* presentation is used.

The behavior can be controlled by two system properties

- `hudson.model.Run.ArtifactList.listCutoff` - Default: 16
- `hudson.model.Run.ArtifactList.treeCutoff` - Default: 40

See [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties) for details.
You can also have a look at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187561/last-successful-artifacts-list) here on StackOverflow.